# How do I use UI Automation with ChromiumWebBrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation, cefsharp

I'm trying to use UI automation with ChromiumWebBrowser, so I managed to make it work by passing `force-renderer-accessibility` command line option to settings. It got available on inspect.exe tool but I still couldn't find it by code. Could anyone just give me a code sample?

Here's how I initialize the `ChromiumWebBrowser`:

```
void InitializeChromiumWebBrowser()
{
    var settings = new CefSettings()
    {
        CefCommandLineArgs = {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("force-renderer-accessibility", "true")
        },
        MultiThreadedMessageLoop = false
    };
    Cef.Initialize(settings);
    m_chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://127.0.0.1/calc.html");
    m_chromeBrowser.Name = "chromiumWebBrowser";
    var t = new Timer { Interval = 5 };
    t.Start();
    t.Tick += (s, e) => BeginInvoke((Action)(() => Cef.DoMessageLoopWork()));
    m_chromeBrowser.LoadingStateChanged += M_chromeBrowser_LoadingStateChanged;
    browser_tabPage.Controls.Add(m_chromeBrowser);
}
```

I'm trying to manipulate them with UI Automation, but I couldn't find even the top window:

```
using (var proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
{
    var root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);
    var browser = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, 
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "CefBrowserWindow")); // Always null
}
```

But `browser` always is `null`. What am I missing?

Comment: I would recommend using Selenium, it is much easier to set up initially, and the documentation is much more in-depth.

Comment: @KevinBBurns Can I use UI Automation with Selenium?

Comment: It is what I use it for all the time; I set up tests for my projects using Selenium. It gives you the ability to manipulate a web page programmatically, and you can do it across any browser that Selenium supports (which is IE, Edge, Firefox, and Chrome.) Check out my project on Github, https://github.com/nopcodex90/FacebookFriendFeedDelimiter. I am using Selenium to open my Facebook account and remove all the crap I don't feel like looking at every day.

Comment: @KevinBBurns Thank you soo much! You saved me day! I've been trying to make it work with cefsharp has been almost a week. I managed to make it work with Selenium in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Jack Post your solution so others can benefit from what you did.